# Displaying/streaming pictures/video when tweet has media hosted somewhere other than TwitPic

Tags: iphone, twitter

I am working on a Twitter application for Iphone, and wanted to display/stream pictures/video when a tweet has media hosted somewhere like yfrog.com, plixi.com, twitvid.com, etc. I did manage this for TwitPic, but didn't for others. If anybody has any idea let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Embedly](http://embed.ly/). It will make it very easy to embed content from a large number of sites.